# Import one module that imports ALL other modules in each module. Is that sensible and even possible?

Tags: python

In C/C++ microcontroller programming I got a lot of folders with source and header files. I got one header file (`driverlib.h`) that includes ALL other header files (Around 50+). In each source (.c) file I just include this `driverlib.h` file and I don't have to worry about any includes. Otherwise it would be a pain to include a bunch of header files in each source file.

Now I want to know, if the same thing is possible in Python. I have got an example project below:

```
fancy_game/
    models/
        player.py
        monster.py
    audio/
        mixer.py
        effects.py
        player.py
    graphics/
        renderer.py
        screen.py
    common/
        constants.py
    main.py
    driverlib.py
```

Is it possible to create a `driverlib.py` in the main directory that just imports all other modules and then import it in each module? Like this:

driverlib.py

```
# Self-written modules
import models.player.py
import models.monster.py
import audio.mixer.py
# ... and so on and so on ...

# Strange modules
import numpy
import matplotlib
# ... and so on and so on ...
```

player.py in models/:

```
import driverlib.py # This includes ALL other modules and I don't have to worry about any imports
```

Answer (score 0):

That what u need is a really bad practice accordin to pep8. Dont do it. Its better to import only that what you going to use and nothing more and manual imports are that what should claim.

Comment: If you want, please delete this answer and post it in the duplicate question